# ajax function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter

on click ... ..

some code....

```
$.ajax({ url: '<?php echo base _ url(); ?>locations/getmap',

        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: location_data,
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert('hi');  //morecode}
```

CONTROLLER location/getmap

```
public function getmap(){
    $type = 'ok';
    echo json_encode($type);
```

Nothing happens on click ... if i put alert before the ajax function .. it works. What should i use in  controller to see if the script is reaching there? I used alert() again nothing happens ... for url i m using base_url method which works on other scripts ..

Comment: Have a look at your browser's developer tools. It will show you which HTTP requests are made (if any). Also attach an `error` handler to your Ajax call.

Comment: your url is wrong in ``url`` - set to ``base_url``

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo base _ url(); ?>
```

should be

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

and it should be set to at least / or it will always be a relative path

Comment: i know .. the stackoverflow was not showing it in preview so i put those sapces ... please ignore that

Comment: you should update your question with the code for click listener. your code doesnt otherwise look wrong unless base_url is resolving to blank and the relative path is wrong

Comment: Thanks Felix ... firebug worked.

The problem was <?php base_url() ?> was not working in ajax function .... the url needed to be changed to just "function name" not even the controller name. 

Still wondering how to solve this URLs problem once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

it is because your ajax function is not working, so the alert works only then if the ajax get success sign from server.
your url in ajax is wrong. please be careful with whitespaces all your life long,
 your url should be like this and your data rendering is also wrong, it should be like this:

```
  $.ajax({ url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>locations/getmap',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {location_data: your_real_data},
    }).done(function(){
        // success to-do        
    })
```

Comment: I PUT THOSE SPACES IN THIS POST AS SATCKOVER FLOW WAS NOT SHOWING THE POST ... PLEASE IGNORE THEM ...!!!!!!!

Comment: fELIX, I tried the browser console .. its says ReferenceError: $ is not defined 

$.ajax({

Comment: @JamilKhan, $ error means, you dont have jquery imported or not correctly imported in your file. put this in html head ``<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>``